remove purchase order PurchaseDashBoard in odoo17
how can i remove purchase order PurchaseDashBoard
in odoo 17
<templates>
    <t t-name="purchase.PurchaseKanbanView" t-inherit="web.KanbanRenderer" t-inherit-mode="primary">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_renderer')]" position="before">
            <PurchaseDashBoard />
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>

<templates>
    <t t-name="purchase.PurchaseListView" t-inherit="web.ListRenderer" t-inherit-mode="primary">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_list_renderer')]" position="before">
            <PurchaseDashBoard />
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>



You could simple hide it with css...
.o_purchase_dashboard{
    display: none !important;    
}

to only hide it on specific views...
.o_list_view .o_purchase_dashboard, .o_kanban_view .o_purchase_dashboard{
display: none !important; 
}

Finally you must include your css file in the __manifest__.py
"assets": {
        "web.assets_backend":[
            "path_to_your_file/purchase_dashboard.css",

        ]
}

Also you could archive the same result using a more odoo like aproach by modifying de component using an xml file...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="my_module.PurchaseDashboard" t-inherit="purchase.PurchaseDashboard" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_purchase_dashboard')]" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class" separator=" " add="d-none"></attribute>
            
        </xpath>
    </t>
      
</templates>

and if you want to remove the component completely from a view...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">   
      
      <t t-name="my_module.PurchaseListView" t-inherit="purchase.PurchaseListView" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//PurchaseDashBoard" position="replace">
            
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>

Don't forget to include de xml file in the __manifest__.py
"assets": {
        "web.assets_backend":[
            "path_to_your_file/purchase_dashboard.xml",

        ]
}


You just need to remove an attribute of the <tree> node of the main view purchase.purchase_order_kpis_tree.
<record id="purchase_order_kpis_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.purchase.order.tree.inherit.remove_dashboard</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_kpis_tree" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree position="attributes">
            <attribute name="js_class" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

That will remove the attribute js_class from the purchase order list view which will remove the dashboard.
